# Best way of drawing text to the screen

Tags: ipad, text, drawing, highlighting

I am working on a read-along-book app for the iPad which is very similar to this Toy Story book ([url=http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/toy-story-read-along/id364376920?mt=8]Toy Story Read-Along for iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad on the iTunes App Store[/url]).  So my question is how would be the best way to draw the text to the screen and then, here seems to be the tricky part, highlight over each word as it is read by the narrator?  I have some pretty nice page turning animation setup now and a few other things on there way, but need some good suggestions for the text.  Any examples are very much welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer only for the text highlighting.

I guess the best way to do it is to create a separate app that play the audio file you want to use.

when the apps starts there will be a button for starting the audio playback.

once pressed play, the app starts a timer.

now you start listening the audio, every time a starts a word that you want to highlight tap the screen.
the app tracks the time.

at the end of the audio file, the apps dumps the timestamps.

at this point you'll have the exact time in which you'll have to start highlighting the single word in your application.

Hope it help!